# Progress bar with z-index property

Tags: android

I want my progress bar on top of everything (and at top of the screen, like normal progress bar you have in your browser). Just like you apply z-index property in CSS, I want to apply the same thing on my Android app.

I'm new to Android & don't know much about it. I tried to search for this property but had no luck.

Here is my code of progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="1dip"
    android:maxHeight="8dip"
    android:minWidth="10dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal" />
```

Can someone tell what property to add in here?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
progressBar = v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.progressbar_id);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.bringToFront();
```